# "Syntax error: missing 'semicolon'" em procedure do MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho a `procedure` abaixo

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_notasAluno`(IN aluno INT)
BEGIN 
  DECLARE ditCodigo,courseId INT;
  DECLARE usuario VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE notafinaloff,notafinalon,somanotaon float;

  select gg.id, SUM(finalgrade) AS notaFinal,SUM(grademax) as NotaMaxima from mdl_grade_grades gg
  INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi on gg.itemid = gi.id
  INNER JOIN mdl_course course ON gi.courseid = course.id
  INNER JOIN mdl_user user ON gg.userid = user.id
  where userid = aluno AND itemmodule like 'assign' GROUP BY itemmodule;

  select @ditCodigo=course.idnumber,@usuario=username,@courseId=course.id,SUM(finalgrade) AS notaFinal from mdl_grade_grades gg
  INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi on gg.itemid = gi.id
  INNER JOIN mdl_course course ON gi.courseid = course.id
  INNER JOIN mdl_user user ON gg.userid = user.id
  where userid = aluno AND itemmodule like 'quiz' GROUP BY itemmodule;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE notas (dit_codigo int,login varchar(50),cur_codigo int,notaOn decimal,notaOff decimal,idNota int, notaOffMax decimal) VALUES ()
END
```

Ao executar acontece o seguinte erro na criação da tabela temporaria:

```
Syntax error: missing 'semicolon'
```

Comment: `Create temporary table` com `VALUES ()`?

Comment: vou adicionar uns parâmetros que recupero de um select...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE notas (dit_codigo int,[login] varchar(50),cur_codigo int,notaOn decimal,notaOff decimal,idNota int, notaOffMax decimal) VALUES ()
END
```

login é uma palavra reservada. Adicionar chaves a ela.

Comment: Como salvo os valores de um select em variáveis?

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE notas (dit_codigo int,[login] varchar(50),cur_codigo int,notaOn decimal,notaOff decimal,idNota int, notaOffMax decimal) select coluna_1, coluna_2, coluna_3, coluna_4, coluna_5, coluna_6, coluna_7 from tabela`